# Getting a collection of all uploaded MultipartFile files

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I'm looking for a map of all uploaded files in Spring like `key => MultipartFile`. The ones I've found so far require me to know the `key` to the file.

Does anyone know a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, it's so simple:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity executeByPost(WebRequest webRequest)
{
    MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> files = ((StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest) ((ServletWebRequest) webRequest).getRequest()).getMultiFileMap();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(files.keySet());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get collection of Part like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadFile")
@ResponseBody
public String handleTestRequest (MultipartHttpServletRequest r) throws IOException, ServletException {
    for (Part part : r.getParts()) {
        String name = part.getName();
        String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(part.getInputStream()))
                  .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

        System.out.println(name + " " + result);

    }
    return "test output";
}
```